# phpstorm не дает редактировать css файлы

Tags: php, css, phpstorm

Использую PhpStorm 9.0 И OpenServer.
При попытке написать что-то в любом файле css, после запуска текст кода меняется на исходный.

Исходный текст

```
    body 
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 15px Arial Narrow, Helvetica, Garuda, sans-serif;
  *font-size: small;
  *font: x-small;
}
```

Изменяем его, допустим ставим строку в комментарий

```
 body 
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 15px Arial Narrow, Helvetica, Garuda, sans-serif;
  *font-size: small;
  /**font: x-small;*/
}
```

После запуска данная строка возвращается в исходное состояние. Как исправить данную ситуацию?

Comment: именно только css? остальные все замечательно сохраняет?))

Comment: Да все остальные файлы сохраняются

Comment: Права на папку есть? не удаленно работаете случаем с папкой? Или плагины в браузере поставлены, которые связаны с проектом аля CSS Reloader и прочие. Из другого редактора сохраняет?

Comment: нет, тестирование происходит на локальном сервере, папка тоже локальная. Единственное что использую это Jet Brains IDE Support, который позволяет сразу видеть изменения

Comment: очень странно. Вы css файлы сами создаете, вручную, или они генерируются из  других файлов (scss, less, styl,...)?

Comment: нет, уже есть файл file.css в котором делаешь изменения, но после запуска в браузере, в файле все меняется в исходное состояние

Comment: Может банально стоит почистить кеш браузера?

Comment: Меняется содержимое файла на диске, на сервере? или просто в браузере отображается старый файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, на сайте применялся препроцессор sass поэтому редактирование отдельно файлов css не имело смысла. Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь